# require.js Consuming an AngularJS directive from a different module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Directive in a module is not being bootstrapped when called by a different module

I have an AngularJS web app with a module in it called 'heroEditor':

```
// 3) heroEditor ng module is created and injects the dataListPane
// module as a dependency (see step 1)
define('heroEditor/module',['common/module', 'dataListPane/module'], function(){
    return angular.module('heroEditor', ['common', 'dataListPane']);
});
```

As you can see above it is depending on another ng module called 'dataListPane' below:

```
// 1) define the dataListPane ng module
define('dataListPane/module',[], function(){
    return angular.module('dataListPane', []);
});
```

This is all wired up through requirejs and everything is called in the right order. In module 'heroEditor' I have a directive, also called 'heroEditor':

```
// 4) Register the heroEditor directive on the heroEditor module
// this directive will try to consume a dataListPane directive instance
// which should be available as it was registered (see step 2)
define('heroEditor/directive/heroEditor',['heroEditor/module', 'heroEditor/service/heroData'], function(heroEditorMod){
    heroEditorMod.directive('heroEditor', ['heroData', function(heroData){
        //hero editor directive definition
    });
});
```

Within the dependency, 'dataListPane' module is a directive that I want to use inside the 'heroEditor' directive's markup. Here's the 'dataListPane' directive:

```
// 2) Register the dataListPane directive on the dataListPane module
define('dataListPane/directive/dataListPane',['dataListPane/module'], function(dataListPaneMod){
    dataListPaneMod.directive('dataListPane', function(){
        // [NEVER CALLED] data list pane directive content
        return {scope:{},templateUrl:'a/valid/path/to/dataListPane.html'};
    });
});
```

In the markup for the hero editor, I try to drop in an instance of the data list pane directive (it should be available!) like so

```
<data-list-pane></data-list-pane>
```

In the browser though the directive function for data list pane never fires despite the fact that I am including it in my markup. Injection from a requirejs perspective is working fine. Ng also doesn't throw an exception when I create the hero editor module and give it the dataListPane module dependency (which means it knows the module exists!)

I am using ng 1.7.2

Any assistance would be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any snippets that indicate how you're pulling together RequireJS modules at a higher up level (e.g. some base `app.js` file). However, I suspect your `dataListPane/directive/dataListPane` module is never part of any RequireJS dependency definitions (i.e. unreachable from `app.js`), which is why the code inside never executes.

One way to ensure declarations on AngularJS-style modules are pulled in is to have the AngularJS module itself ensure the code for such declarations are executed.

```
// dataListPane/module.js
define(
    'dataListPane/module',
    ['dataListPane/directive/dataListPane'],
    function (dataListPane) {
        var mod = angular.module('dataListPane', []);
        return function () {
            dataListPane.init(mod);
            return mod;
        };
    });

// dataListPane/directive/dataListPane.js
define(
    'dataListPane/directive/dataListPane',
    // You cannot depend on 'dataListPane/module' here! (i.e. cyclic dependency)
    ['exports'],
    function (exports) {
        exports.init = function (mod) {
            // mod.directive(...)
        };
    });
```

[I've made a working demonstration of this approach here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/QUZuH4TwrdiBS4KwizNU?p=preview)

Two points about the approach above:

1. The separated directive definition (i.e. `dataListPane` in your case) cannot explicitly depend on the AngularJS module it needs to be declared on, otherwise it's a cyclic dependency
2. Notice the AngularJS module explicitly depends on the RequireJS module the directive definition resides in and initialises it

Comment: Not seeing any cyclic require dependencies. When you require the "main.js", main requires the directive which then requires the ng module, which is needed first so you can hang the directive off the module. I actually have this working on a higher level in the dependency tree. I have a theory that there is a bug in angular that only reproduces in these specific circumstances. What a bummer. Without this working I will be copying and pasting lots of duplicate code. Oh well.

Comment: I updated my original post with steps showing the sequence. They are out of order with respect to when they happen but I know for a fact that those define() callbacks are indeed called in that order, 1,2,3,4. This has to be a rare but consistent bug in angular, no other explanation.

Comment: It'd help if you showed how you're setting up your RequireJS dependencies in "main.js" so we can establish the run-time dependency graph. Please check out my minimal example if you haven't already. This is not an AngularJS bug. The order in which `define` calls are made is irrelevant. It's the _incomplete traversal of module definitions_ by RequireJS at run-time (based on dependencies specified per module encountered) which has led to you seeing what you're seeing.